# Проблема с получением атрибутов XML C#

Tags: c#, xml

Есть такой xml-документ:

```
<Capability>
  <Layer queryable="1">
  <Name>infras_0</Name>
   <Layer displayField="id" queryable="1" visible="1">
   <Name>BBRQ_копия20170315084719786</Name>
   <Title>BBRQ copy</Title>
   <Style>
     <Name>default</Name>
   </Style>
   <Attributes>
    <Attribute precision="0" length="-1" editType="TextEdit" type="int" comment="" name="id" />
    <Attribute precision="0" length="-1" editType="TextEdit" type="qlonglong" comment="" name="objectid" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="10" editType="TextEdit" alias="Код классификации" type="QString" comment="" name="код_класси" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="100" editType="TextEdit" type="QString" comment="" name="наименован" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="100" editType="TextEdit" type="QString" comment="" name="подпись" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="-1" editType="TextEdit" type="double" comment="" name="uwi" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="100" editType="TextEdit" type="QString" comment="" name="предприяти" />
    <Attribute precision="-1" length="50" editType="TextEdit" type="QString" comment="" name="площадь" />
   </Attributes>
  </Layer>
 </Layer>
</Capability>
```

То что уже написано:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("input.xml");
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
            {
                // получаем атрибут name
                if (childnode.Name == "Name")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", childnode.InnerText);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                foreach (XmlNode childnode1 in childnode)
                {
                    if (childnode1.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", childnode1.InnerText);
                    }
                    if (childnode1.Name == "Title")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tTitle: {0}", childnode1.InnerText);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:
[image: Результат выполнения]

Не обращайте внимание на последние 2 вывода, просто исходный xml-документ больше, не стал зассорять пространство. Вопрос в том, как получить доступ к

```
<Attributes>
 ...
</Atrributes>
```

И его элементам в xml-документе. Как я понял это XNode, но при обращении к childnode1.ChildNodes приходит null.

Comment: `</Layer>
 </Layer>`  ??

Comment: @Igor там перед этим два открывающих Layer, все ок

Comment: @PashaPash а, да. Пардон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("input.xml");
        XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

        foreach (XmlNode xnode in xRoot)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
            {
                // получаем атрибут name
                if (childnode.Name == "Name")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", childnode.InnerText);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                foreach (XmlNode childnode1 in childnode)
                {
                    if (childnode1.Name == "Name")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", childnode1.InnerText);
                    }
                    if (childnode1.Name == "Title")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tTitle: {0}", childnode1.InnerText);
                    }
                    //ловим Node с именем "Attributes"
                    if (childnode1.Name == "Attributes")
                    {
                        //делаем цикл по ChildNodes
                        foreach (XmlNode attr in childnode1.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            XmlNode k = attr.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
                            Console.WriteLine("\t"+k.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Оказывается при объявлении переменной вот так:

```
var attr = childnode1.ChildNodes;
```

VS почему то думает, что "attr" является типом object и присваивает значение null. Поэтому в данном случае лучше обойтись без var и указывать тип переменной:

```
XmlNode attr = childnode1.ChildNodes;
```